# SQL to list users with role=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Rails app using PG.
I would like to use pgAdmin to search for certain users roles.

This didn't work:

```
select * from users where user.role? :admin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a `role` column in your `users` table :

```
select * from users where users.role = 'admin';
```

Looks like you missed an `S` at the end of user on `user.role`

For simple queries,this is enough :

```
select * from users where role = 'admin';
```